# Cleanest way to wait until API returns expected response

Tags: java, rest, testing

I am writing test automation, and I stumble upon places, where I need to wait for something to happen server side. The only way I can verify it happend, is to call API and get expected response. I just `Thread.sleep` a static time and call API being 99% sure result is positive. And it is, however I have to wait like 20s. I would like to move to something more robust and time efficient - for example selenium has fluent waits for waiting on elements (which I use).

Let's say I want to register an user. After clicking sumbit I wait static 20s, before calling Mailtrap API to check if mail with verification code for specific user has been sent. Usually email get sent instanteniously, but sometimes it take few seconds. So I wait full 20s, not to get flakes.

```
    public CreateAccountStep registerAndVerifyAccount(@NotNull User user) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {
        log.debug("Register account and verify an email.");
        registerAccount(user);
        Utils.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        verifyEmail(user.email());
        return this;
    }
```

```
    private void verifyEmail(String email) throws IOException {
        MailtrapMessage message = Mailtrap.findLatestEmail(email);
        Assert.equal(message.subject(), "Verify your email and complete registration", "Check message subject");
        new RegisterPO(driver)
                .loadPageFromConfirmationLink(Mailtrap.getLinkFromEmail(message))
                .clickLoginBtn();
    }
```

```
    public MailtrapMessage findLatestEmail(String recipientEmail) throws IOException {
        return Arrays
                .stream(readMessages().as(MailtrapMessage[].class))
                .filter(email -> email.to_email().equals(recipientEmail))
                .toList()
                .get(0);
    }
```

I think I could have probed every 5 second for verification email, but then however, my method can find unrelated email to the same email address. (In registration case I can be pretty sure it will be unique, however I have many other notifications, like reset password, remind sth, and so on) Also there are API quotas, which would block API considering parallel execution.

What is my best solution to optimize this very long wait time, without compromising API quotas or clogging memory (API responses tend to be very big).

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @SakshiSingla I only added custom retry mechanism to try thrice if null pointer is thrown (email has not arrived). My company's architect said that if it works I shouldn't fix it.